# HTML cookies not working with android webview

Tags: c#, android, cookies, webview

I am using android webview for my asp.net web application and the below code suppose to change the country selected which is working fine with web browser but its not working with android webview as inside webview when i click on this button it move me to index.aspx but the country remain as it was chosen before he did not take the new value of the cookie

```
protected void chgcontrybtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["countryCookies"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["countryCookies"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);//to remove cookies

            Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
        }

        else if (Request.Cookies["Location"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies["Location"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

            Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this..

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= "Your SDK VERSION"){
  CookieManager cookieManager = cookieManager.getInstance();
  cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are almost as useless as link-only answers. Please explain what the issue is, and why your proposed solution addresses it.

Answer (score 0):

on android side you must enable cookie, **before you initialize your webview**

```
CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
```

CookieManager.getInstance() is the CookieManager instance for your entire application. Then, you will enable cookies for all the webviews in your application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply this line has been added already but the problem is its takes time until it change and accept the new cookie value